# Queries on architecture of production pipeline for a batch predictions

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model, data-science-model, prediction

I have a Problem statement to predict Expected delivery time (in days) and below is the information we have from client.

1. Prediction to be batch inference.
2. Each batch inference to have millions of records in Production
3. Predicted outcome with LIVE data need to be stored in RDBMS Database
4. Regression problem statement where we need to predict number of days as Expected delivery time.

We have build the model in Databricks using Scikit-Learn and below are couple of my queries.

1. Do we need to include feature engineering steps (feature encoding, feature scaling, outlier detection, dimensionality reduction) in production pipeline for predicting LIVE data (Hyperparameter tuning step won't be included here for sure)
2. I will have over million records in production to predict the outcome, after predicting outcome for each row for LIVE data, how to plug back the output (no. of days) to original data for further use.

Please guide me having this information, I have been searching through internet but these topics are not much talked in detail.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey @gunes, could you please help me here with the queries